# Обращение к свойствам модели в camelCase

Tags: laravel, laravel5, eloquent

Можно ли настроить модель таким образом, чтобы была возможность обращаться к ее свойствам, используя `camelCase` наименование? К примеру, если в таблице `USERS` базы данных есть поле `is_admin`, обратиться к соответствующему свойству как `$user->isAdmin`.

Comment: можно переопределить __get() и там его уже дергать

Comment: Да он по умолчанию так и делает

Comment: @Orange_shadow, странно, потому что у меня не так, но доступ по `camelCase` наименованию возвращает `null`, а доступ по `snake_case` - реальное значение.

Comment: Мда возможно я с чем то попутал

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решает это [расширение](https://github.com/kirkbushell/eloquence)

Необходимо добавить в начало файла с моделью следующую строку:

```
use Eloquence\Behaviours\CamelCasing;
```

А также, в самом классе:

```
use CamelCasing;
```